# When adding ip address to block on router it says invalid ip address

Tags: router, ip-address, blocking

I'm trying to block skype at the router and when I add an address such as 111.221.74.0 it says "Invalid IP address:111.221.74.0!". I'm using a Cisco DPC3825. Any ideas how to block the IP address?

@Nixda still no good
[image: screen shot or router rejecting ip address]

Here's a screen shot of under basic rules. I can't understand how to add entries.

[image: access/restrictions/basic rule]

I tried adding dns0.skype.net but I'm not sure if it got added correctly.

Comment: well, dot 0 at the end is wrong wrong. 'cos .0 is for a subnet(for when specifying a range of IPs) not for an individual machine. Try checking the IP of the machine you want to block again.

Comment: @barlop I'm following these directions http://pingtool.org/block-skype-connection/

Comment: The example address is invalid...

Comment: @Ramhound No it is a valid IP address. Just to represent a subnet though, one for a single device. As I said.

Comment: @Celeritas  That webpage says it's for networks (subnets).  See the forward slash after the IP address.  111.221.74.0/24   That means hold the first 24 bits, and vary the last 8. So it's the whole range 111.222.74.0-255    How to vary - I don't know about that router, you could add a cisco tag to your question and title.

Comment: The highest and lowest address in a network are best avoided. The highest because it is the broadcast address. The lowest because it used to be a broadcast address and many devices still treat it as special. I see no reason why you can not technically use it (according to the RFCs), but you will run into problems with many devices. Add to that that Cisco is 'somewhat special' and you found the source of your problem.

Comment: Some links to back that up: http://serverfault.com/questions/451238/why-cant-all-zeros-in-the-host-portion-of-ip-address-be-used-for-a-host and http://superuser.com/questions/379451/why-can-a-network-address-not-be-a-valid-host-address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Some basics you need to know first

1. `111.221.74.0/24` isn't a valid IP because an IP with [an ending zero is the network identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Addresses_ending_in_0_or_255)
2. A following backslash with a number is an alternative notation for a [subnet mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference)

   ```
   111.221.74.0   <- network identifier
   255.255.255.0  <- subnet mask
   ```

   This subnet mask is in decimal writing. If we convert both numbers to binaries, you will see that there are 8 zeros and 24 ones. That's where the `/24` came from

   ```
   0110 1111.1101 1101.0100 1010.0000 0000  <- network identifier
   1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.0000 0000  <- subnet mask
   |______ network prefix _____| |_hosts_|
   ```
3. The zeros define (mask) the valid first and last IP for hosts of that network

   ```
   0110 1111.1101 1101.0100 1010.0000 0001  <- first valid IP address for hosts
   0110 1111.1101 1101.0100 1010.1111 1110  <- last valid IP address for hosts
   ```
4. The `1111 1111` (=255) is reserved for the broadcast address

   ```
   0110 1111.1101 1101.0100 1010.1111 1111  <- broadcast address
   ```

---

#### Back to your router problem

A look at the [Cisco DPC3825 manual (site 60)](http://www.cisco.com/web/consumer/support/userguides2/4021196_B.pdf) reveals that your router wants the start and end IP to block a whole range of IP addresses. For `111.221.74.0/24` the start/end address would be `111.221.74.1` and `111.221.74.254`.

[image]

#### Edit

You cannot enter these skype IPs under "Access Restrictions > IP Address Filtering". This subpage is only for outbound traffic respectively IPs from local hosts which are connected to your router. Usually they begin with `192.168.xxx.yyy`. For example, to block your child's laptop you would enter (start:) 192.168.1.100 - (end:) 192.168.1.100. The cisco router checks if an entered IP is within the range of 192.168.xxx.yyy and since it's not he states "invalid IP".

You want to block inbound traffic for specific IPs. As far as I can tell, this seems impossible for your Cisco DPC3825 (which runs a Linksys software btw). Your best chance is under "Access > Basic Rules" since your [Skype block guide](http://pingtool.org/block-skype-connection/) says

```
Currently there are 16 DNS entries from dsn0.d.skype.net to dsn16.dsn.skype.net.
```

Try to enter URLs instead of IPs

```
dsn0.d.skype.net
dsn1.d.skype.net
...    
dsn16.d.skype.net
```

You may reach the maximum of blocking rules. If this happens, try if wildcards (*, ?) are allowed: `dsn*.d.skype.net`

[image]

Comment: I tried but it still says invalid IP address (see update)

Comment: I see the problem. Read my edit :)

Comment: @Celeritas Any updates with your issue? Have you solved it?

Comment: Actually I kind of gave up but I'll let you know if I come back to it.

Comment: @Celeritas Sad to hear :-/

Comment: I tried adding dns0.skype.net to the list at the top. I'm not sure if it worked or not. I can't understand the UI? (see edit on question)

Answer (score 2):

111.221.74.0 is a network, not a site. If you you want, you can block all sites belonging to that network by specifying 111.221.74.0/24, or alternatively you may block only one specific member of the network, say 111.221.74.173.